# Windows 10 Excel 2016 - SQL Server 2008 R2 Log in suddenly slow

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a connection between Excel 2016 and SQL Server 2008 R2 and use it to load some queries into different sheets.

Everything used to work perfect, but this morning I started getting huge delays when refreshing the queries - Excel goes to not responding, freezes, and around 30 secs later, finally, refreshes. It drives me crazy, because this happens for every single query and I am refreshing around 40 of them...

My colleagues have the same file and **do not** experience any delay.

I am running Windows 10, they are running both Windows 10 and Windows 7.

I did a system restore from last week (when it used to work fine) - same behavior...

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

If you have restored your PC, the only elements unchanged are, as far as I understand, the contents of the sheets or something you cannot reset.

If your colleagues have the same files, with the same software and no problem, consider checking your hardware. The factory reset having done nothing, and the problem not coming from the files itself, only your phisical machine remains hypothetically faulty.

Also, take a look at the performances while the queries are being executed by using the **Task Manager** (in its *Advanced Mode*). This might give you a general idea of what is going on.

Try executing queries on another server/db if you can and compare the results.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried setting up a new excel file linked to the same DB and I get the same delay even when trying to set up the connection (the initial log in without running any queries). No spikes in resource utilization either...

Comment: Is there any difference in specs between your machine and the ones your colleagues use ? Is the DB considerably _"large"_ ? Can you use another DB ? I'm sorry to ask so many questions but I'm just troubleshooting until we can at least locate the origin of the issue.
If your computer does not seem to "suffer" from any overload, then I don't really see where it could come from.

Comment: My machine is much more powerful and used to work perfectly until today. Queries have not changed the, DB size has not changed. It is obviously connected to my machine. I tried switching the network from LAN to WIFI, but still no change in behavior :(

Comment: I just now read about a similar problem here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072021/slow-running-query-on-my-machine-only

Try updating your drivers, maybe an update has caused issues with performance. If you do not have the same machine than your colleagues do, that might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After trying several things including update of drivers, system restore, new odbc setup, restarting the SQL server services and getting no results, I decided to restart the server itself and the problem is now gone...

I can only assume there was some bug with the SQL server itself.

Thanks to everyone for helping. This question is now closed.